# <xsl:comment> doesn't appear in my output

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012 when I run my XML transformation using the built-in XML debugger, it prints the comments to the output just fine. But when I run the transformation from my C# code, it doesn't print the comments at all. Crazy making me it is.

```
<xsl:comment>hi there</xsl:comment>

XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform(true);
xslt.Load(xsltFile.FullName);
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(tempFile.FullName))
{
    xslt.Transform(inputFile.FullName, xsltArgs, sw);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the `XsltMessageEncountered` event on the `XsltArgumentList` type.

Instead of using the `xsl:comment` tag use the `xsl:message` tag instead.

```
xsltArgs.XsltMessageEncountered += (o,e) => { Console.WriteLine(e); };

XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform(true);
xslt.Load(xsltFile.FullName);
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(tempFile.FullName))
{
    xslt.Transform(inputFile.FullName, xsltArgs, sw);
}
```

Comment: Sorry - I figured it out.  In my C# code, I was doing a 2nd transformation that was stripping out the comments.  :-/

Comment: Interesting tho...Appears to be a debugging technique.  I don't see how I could have used it to write XML comments to the output.

Comment: @phil.hadley no probs, either post as answer or edit your question, although I don't think I answered your question anyway

Comment: Not the correct answer, but I'll give you the points for the quick response and educational info.  :-)